# Using scikit-learn in Julia through PyCall

Tags: python, scikit-learn, julia

I'm trying to use Scikit-learn in Julia through [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl).

As a start, I'm trying to read the iris data into a Julia data structure.

This is the code in Python:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

The PyCall documentation says Python methods are called in Julia like, for example:

```
my_dna[:find]("ACT")
```

as opposed to:

```
my_dna.find("ACT")
```

in Python.

My attempt to do import the iris data in Julia is:

```
using PyCall
@pyimport sklearn.datasets as datasets
@pyimport sklearn.naive_bayes as NB

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = ...?
Y = ...?
```

The `iris = datasets.load_iris()` call works where `iris` is then a `Dict{Any,Any}` type.

I'm not sure if this correct. I tried `iris = datasets[:load_iris]` instead but this results in:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching getindex(::Module, ::Symbol)
```

Going further, how would I read `iris.data` and `iris.target` into `X` and `Y`?

Comment: What about using ScikitLearn.jl?

Comment: Hi Chris. I did see that, but I like the idea of using the official sklearn release as I am not sure how fast ScikitLearn.jl is being developed and if it will keep up with the speed at which Julia is being developed. Is that a silly line of reasoning?

Comment: ScikitLearn.jl is quite actively being developed. And anything that's missing you could contribute just as easily as using PyCall itself. So I wouldn't shy away from it. However, it might not work today... but that's an unrelated issue due to some really weird issue in the package ecosystem that cropped up today... but that kind of issue is rare.

Comment: Cool, I will check it out!

Comment: Chris, trying sklearn.jl results in the error : `WARNING: Method definition require(Symbol) in module Base at loading.jl:345 overwritten in module Main at /Users/user/.julia/v0.5/Requires/src/require.jl:12.
ERROR: LoadError: PyError (:PyImport_ImportModule) <type 'exceptions.ImportError'>
ImportError('No module named sklearn.linear_model',)` when I try to run the quickstart guide example. Do you know if that has to do with the current problem they are having?

Comment: No, the problem I mentioned has been fixed (it was due to a dependency of theirs that affected other libraries as well, and was just an issue for a few hours). This problem is more directly related to ScikitLearn.jl itself. I would open an issue on their Github for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, Julia tells you what type `iris` is:

```
julia v0.5> @pyimport sklearn.datasets as datasets

julia v0.5> @pyimport sklearn.naive_bayes as NB

julia v0.5> iris = datasets.load_iris()
Dict{Any,Any} with 5 entries:
  "feature_names" => Any["sepal length (cm)","sepal width (cm)","petal length (…
  "target_names"  => PyObject array(['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'], …
  "data"          => [5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2; 4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2; … ; 6.2 3.4 5.4 2.3; 5.…
  "target"        => [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0  …  2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]
  "DESCR"         => "Iris Plants Database\n====================\n\nNotes\n----…
```

It also tells you what the keys in the dictionary are.
So now you just use Julia's syntax for accessing values in a dictionary (result snipped):

```
julia v0.5> X = iris["data"]
150×4 Array{Float64,2}:
 5.1  3.5  1.4  0.2
 4.9  3.0  1.4  0.2
 4.7  3.2  1.3  0.2

julia v0.5> Y = iris["target"]
150-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 0
```

Note that I did not know the answer to this question. I just let Julia guide me as to what to do.

Finally, as @ChrisRackauckas suggested, there is already a Julia package that wraps scikit-learn: https://github.com/cstjean/ScikitLearn.jl

Comment: Thank you David, see my comment on Chris's post, and perhaps also comment if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

Since there were some changes, I'd like to add the current syntax of of `PyCall` (currently version 1.91.4) in addition to Davids answer.

The python code

```py
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

iris = datasets.load_iris()

X = iris.data
y = iris.target
```

becomes in Julia:

```
using PyCall
datasets = pyimport("sklearn.datasets")
GaussianNB = pyimport("sklearn.naive_bayes")
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris["data"]
y = iris["target"]
```